# Aggregator module block shows up only to registered users

Tags: blocks

I am using the aggregator module for D8, I have created a few blocks with feeds from various media outlets. The problem is that the blocks show up only to registered users of the site. How can everybody see them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the role permissions on the blocks? On block layout, you should be able to click on Configure. This should take you to the administration screen for the block in question. There you should see a tab layout with an option for Roles. Do you have items there checked?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just checked the options for Roles and there is nothing checked there, no restrictions found